# Open source code about the basic Quisquater-Piret DFA of AES-128

Tags: attack, cryptographic-hardware

Where can i find open source code about the basic Quisquater-Piret DFA of AES-128? Are there any websites sharing the code about such physical attacks?

Comment: Sorry, but code requests and link requests are off topic.